# Android Switch setOnCheckedChangeListener method to pass Object by applying DRY principle

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, dry

```
toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            try
            {
                String msg ="";
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled

                    //msg = "Hello " + String.valueOf(!isChecked);
                    msg = "1";


                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    //msg = "Hello " + String.valueOf(!isChecked);
                    msg = "1";
                }
                msg += "\n";
                outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
            catch (NullPointerException ex) { }



        }
    });
```

Please consider the above code. Now I have 1 Switch this code snippet is good enough. However, if I have 4 Switchs so 4 times repeat this code snippet. So this is duplicate. 
Here for each switch toggl1 ->msg = "1";  for toggl2 ->msg = "2"; **Just this change each place.**

How I can pass  object to **setOnCheckedChangeListener** so that I can obey DRY principle ?

Comment: Create your own OnCheckedChangListener (that extends original one) and pass the object with the constructor

Comment: @Chol if you share your code I will learn from it. Ya I have tried to create. But CompoundButton class needs Context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tag of the `View` and retrieve it later like this

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        try {
            String msg ="";
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled

                //msg = "Hello " + String.valueOf(!isChecked);
                msg = buttonView.getTag().toString()


            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                //msg = "Hello " + String.valueOf(!isChecked);
                msg = buttonView.getTag().toString()
            }
            msg += "\n";
            outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex) {

        }
    }
};

toggle1.setTag("1");
toggle2.setTag("2");
toggle3.setTag("3");

toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
toggle3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

The `buttonView` passed by `onCheckChanged` is the switch you toggled, which is always one of your toggle variables

Comment: }); I can not match with (

Comment: Updated. Forgot to remove ')'

Comment: It works. How data is being passed by setTag?  I want to explore it.

Comment: Tag is a member of the View class. It can be used for all kind of purposes, like yours

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom checked Listener:

```
private class customChecked implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    String msg;
    public customChecked(String mMsg){
        this.msg= mMsg;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        myString = msg;
    }
}
```

Then apply:

```
toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new customChecked(1));
toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new customChecked(2));
```

Comment: Your solution Is more transparent